# I want to use ID which is received from first API Call as a candidate entry for my second API ( Different service) In RestSharp ..Specflow scenario

Tags: api, restsharp, specflow

In RestAPI specflow in VS2022 : I made one API call and received ID in response content. Now I want to use that ID (which is received from first API Call ) as a candidate entry for my second API ( Different service) In RestSharp ..Specflow scenario like

```
Given : a API is healthy 
    When  I create user throught the API (x)
            | Field     | Value             |
            | Firstname | PersonName        |
            | Lastname  | SurName           |   
    And  I make a get call for another service with ID generated from API(x)
    Then  the API should returns a "success" response
```

Above scenario is description only

I did use in the stepdefination till received USER ID but then ....?

Comment: Any pointers would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: More Precise description ::::
I have first API call which gets me ID and once I have got the ID from this api , only then I need to make the second api get call (/api/<Id>/) . It must happen in the series and not parallelly. How can I do this in RestSharp Specflow in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [context injection](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings.html#context-injection), which allows you to share data between steps.

Generally, it follows this format:

1. Create a class that holds the data your test is interested in. This is use case specific and should match the needs of your testing framework.
2. Register an instance of this class with the dependency injection framework in SpecFlow.
3. Declare this class as a constructor parameter in your step definitions, and assign it to a field or property.
4. Use it in a step definition.

For your use case, this would be a good starting point.

First, create a class to hold test data using types and property names that make sense for the application you are testing. As an example:

```cs
public class ApiTestData
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This class can be simple. Don't over complicate this. It will hold data you want to share between steps.

Next, register it with the DI container:

```cs
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;

    public Hooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        var testData = new ApiTestData();

        container.RegisterInstanceAs(testData);
    }
}
```

After that, you can add `ApiTestsDate testData` to the constructor parameters of any step definition class to get an instance of this object. To create the user:

```cs
[Binding]
public class UserApiSteps
{
    private readonly ApiTestData testData;

    public ApiSteps(ApiTestData testData)
    {
        this.testData = testData;
    }

    [When(@"I create user throught the API \(x\)")]
    public void CreateApiUser()
    {
        var response = // call the web API, get the response

        testData.UserId = response.UserId; // change this to suite your needs
    }
}
```

And finally to use the Id in another step:

```cs
[Binding]
public class OtherApiSteps
{
    private readonly ApiTestData testData;

    public OtherApiSteps(ApiTestData testData)
    {
        this.testData = testData;
    }

    [When(@"I make a get call for another service with ID generated from API\(x\)")]
    public void MakeOtherCall()
    {
        var userId = testData.UserId;

        // make API call with `userId`
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dee: If this answers your question, feel free to up-vote my post, and click the check mark icon to mark this as the answer.

Comment: you don't need to register it in the container do you? Specflow will create an instance for the scenario automatically for you I believe if its a simple poco like above...

Comment: @SamHolder: to be honest, I've never tried.